# why doesn't my live server work in visual studio code?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

[image: image of live server]

My live server on visual studio keeps opening an old html file when i try to open my current one. Ive tried reinstalling the extension but its the same problem. Can anyone help please

Comment: Uninstall the extension, close your IDE. Open again and install the extension.

Comment: same issue keeps opening an older html file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i cannot have two project folders with an html file running through the live server. Only one html file can be streamed at one time other wise when trying to stream the second, it will stream the first (Like the issue i was having)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem but later on I find out that, I renamed my project folder while my server was still loading the same project but with the previous folder name so I changed the link to my new folder folder name and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have live server will simply not work if there was an error in JavaScript file.

Even if you do an alert in the beginning of JavaScript file (for test purposes) but at the end of the file re-define a variable which was already defined before, this error will render liver server not working.

The html page will not respond as well.

Solution is to go to developer tools (F12), see the errors on console, fix them and save and the live server would be back in action! At least that was the case with me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, sometimes it was an error on the console, or keep showing an old HTML, tried everything, deleting cookies, reinstalling everything and nothing worked,

Eventually, it worked with a hard refresh, what it really worked was to

Go to ---> vs code settings ----> extensions ---> live server config set as chrome private. So far no more errors!

[image]

Answer (score -1):

The liveserver extension serves static pages like html files and it does not load javascript or typescript files. You need to setup a server yourself for example in react you use webpack to configure your local server and your app runs on a localhost:port. In a nutshell, you need to write a script for node to run your js files. And you won't need liveserver after that.

Comment: my html page is what im trying to show but it keeps live serving and old deleted html file withs js still connected - i cant live my new html files as it keeps thinking im trying to open my old one

Comment: That should not happen. Anyways, restart your system maybe that clears out the memory and then try again. It maybe because when you used liveserver on your previous project, you did not abort it and the process is still running in the background. try opening that project again see the liveserver if running on the bottom right of VS Code.